# Which IDE is best to use VIM 7 or VS2012 for python?

Tags: python, ide

As I'm a very beginner in OOP in Python . It is very hard to find the best IDE, I searched a lot then I came up with two suggestions Vim and Visual studio 2012,although both require some plugins to make it work as a Python IDE.

Like "pytools" for VS2012.

Comment: What is "Vim 2.0"? The current major release of vim is 7.

Comment: Oh! Gosh I didn't know that @dope ghoti

Comment: @dope I edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VIM is not an IDE, and VS2012 is not for Python. Try IDLE or PyCharm. You can also use Eclipse with PyDev.